# Selecting from a list of previously selected elements via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of a brain fart here, and hoping someone can help me find a 1-line solution to this problem, without having to call `.each()`.

So I get a list of all checkboxes within a container like this:

```
var checkboxes = $(':checkbox', '#surveyModal');
```

At some point later, I need to find out if any (or none) of the checkboxes are checked within that list.

I expected something like these to work:

```
$(':checked', checkboxes)
// or
checkboxes.attr(':checked')
// or    
$(checkboxes).attr(':checked')
```

But it doesn't.  The only thing I've had success with is calling `each()` and then checking each individually.  But that means I'll have to keep a separate variable (.e.g. `someAreChecked` at a higher-level scope, which I don't feel is optimal.

```
    checkboxes.each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            someAreChecked = true;
        }
    });
```

I was hoping that I can easily in a single line do such a check:

```
if (checkboxes.('get checked count') == 0)
{
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter function is what you're looking for :)

```
checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!  Ugh... I did mention it was a brain fart, right?  :)

Comment: @Kon thats why I keep their documentation in a pinned tab, lol

Answer (score 1):

`.attr` returns the value of an attribute, and you have to pass the attribute's name to it, not a selector.

Just use [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) instead.

> Description: Check the current matched set of elements against a
>   selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of
>   these elements matches the given arguments.

```
$(checkboxes).is(':checked')
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly as well!  Though I'd like to actually retrieve the checked ones, so @Greg's answer works better for my particular case.  But this is great.. upvoting also.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][checked]").length
```

Comment: This returns the same result as Greg, but whatever.

Comment: I don't want to reselect from the whole DOM again.  I wanted to filter on a previously selected list of elements.  That's the whole point of the question.